# Error while adding servlet mapping for path

Tags: java, servlets, mapping

I am trying to deploy my application on a local Websphere Application Server (Version "8.5.5.5").

If I click "Run on Server", I always get:

> ***Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/xcc-admin/test/query,
>   wrapper-->ServletWrapper[XCCAdminServlet.XCCAdminMain:[/XCCAdminMain,
>   /xcc-admin/rest/query, /xcc-admin/test/query]],
>   application-->xcc-admin.***

Code:

```
package XCCAdminServlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.annotation.Resource.AuthenticationType;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class XCCAdminMain
 */
@WebServlet({"/XCCAdminMain", "/xcc-admin/rest/query", "/xcc-admin/test/query"})
@Resource(name = "jdbc/MyDataSource", type = javax.sql.DataSource.class, shareable = true, authenticationType = AuthenticationType.CONTAINER)
public class XCCAdminMain extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "XCCAdminUnit")
  private EntityManagerFactory emf;

  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
   */
  public XCCAdminMain() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/{param}")
  public Response getQuery(@PathParam("param") String msg) throws ServletException {
    return Response.status( 200 ).entity( "Get Request received, queryparam: " + msg ).build();
  }
}
```

How to fix this?